# Gson toJson method returning empty

Tags: java, json, svn, gson

I am attempting to take  List of objects of type SearchResultView  that I have and convert it to a Json string using Googles Gson library, v 2.3.

The following is the relevant code(which I wrote by mimiking the documentation https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#getAdapter-com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken-

```
Type typeResults = new TypeToken<List<SearchResultView>>(){}.getType();
String resultsJSON = (new Gson()).toJson(resultsView.getResults(), typeResults);
System.out.println(resultsJSON); //To test output.
```

The printline prints the following:

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}...
```

I have already verified that

```
resultsView.getResults()
```

returns an object of type

```
List<SearchResultView>
```

and that the list itself is not null and nonempty.  What could be the issue here?

EDIT(Upon request):  SearchResultView is an interface of all 'get' and 'has' methods.  The object in the list is just a bunch of objects which implement that interface.

Comment: You shouldn't need a `Type` here. In any case, post your `SearchResultView` class.

Comment: I just posted it in the edit.

Comment: Ok, show us the class (that implements `SearchResultView`) of one of the instances in the `List`.